# NextJs i18n without any routing?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi i like to add i18n support to my nextJs app without any routing. Any existing solutions I’ve found using some sort of routing.

So what i need is to access request headers ('Accept-Language' header to be spesific) in _document.tsx than I will set html lang from it. Than I read it from Js and return proper language objects both initial ssr and csr. If I do it without this I get error like Text content did not match. Server: …

So far I’ve tried to retrieve it from getInitialProps in _document.tsx but it seems it is always null. I also tried retrieving header from middleware and than rewriting url with adding lang to search params. But I also couldn’t manage to retrieve it from _document.tsx either.

How can I provide this functionality to my app?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [react-intl-universal](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal) with next.js.

You could use [intl.determineLocale](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal/blob/master/packages/react-intl-universal/examples/browser-example/pages/index.tsx#L59-L62) to get the language, then use it to `intl.init`. It has nothing to do with routing.

Here is an example [integrating react-intl-universal with NextJS](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal/tree/master/packages/react-intl-universal/examples/browser-example)